# How to convert negative values in variable, class <chr>, into numeric/integer without receiving NAs?

Tags: r, integer, character, na, numeric

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

In my dataframe(x) I want to convert the values in variable 1 and 2 into numerical/integer as well and also replace the "," into "."
class(x)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Nls.png) "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

I already managed for variable 1:
x$1 <- as.numeric(str_replace(x$1, ",", "."))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Nls.png)

For variable 2 I get NAs for the negative elements in the variable when I tried to convert with
x$2 <- as.numeric(str_replace(x$2, ",", ".")) and
x$2 <- as.integer(str_replace(x$2, ",", "."))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV9oq.png)

I tried also with as.numeric(as.character(factor)).
I got the NAs in very line in variable 2 wherever I had negative values. For the positive ones I could manage to convert them with as.integer.

Could you help me please to convert the negative values in variable 2 into numerical/integer?

I really appreciate your support!

Comment: It may be that the `-` is a different symbol

Comment: @akrun: Thanks akrun. Would you have any idea to check?

Comment: I would try to copy the same symbol from your post, replace it first and then do the conversion `as.numeric(str_replace(str_replace("−3,6", "−", "-"), ",", "."))#
[1] -3.6`

Comment: Thank you. It works when I take the strings out e.g. "-3,6" but when I try to convert the whole variable x$2 it does not work.  as.numeric(str_replace(str_replace(x$2, "−", "-"), ",", "."))

Comment: You can use the column name `as.numeric(str_replace(str_replace(x[["2"]], "−", "-"), ",", "."))#`

Comment: Thanks a lot, akrun. I still get the NAs though. It ist just working for the positive alements of variable 2.

Comment: Can you post a `dput` of an example that shows the issue so that it can be tested